# For loop not working properly? What did I do wrong?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd, scripting

I'm not sure what's wrong the expected output is "0 5 25 100".

The output I get is "20 3 15 60":

[image: http://imgur.com/gallery/qBlt3]

http://hastebin.com/tibirakoni.dos

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion  
cls  
:vars  
set numbercheck=50  
set number2=0  
set number3=0  
set number4=0  
:calc  
for %%a in (0, 1, 100) do (  
    if !numbercheck GEQ 10 (  
        set /a numbercheck= !numbercheck! - 10  
        set /a number2= !number2! +1  
        set /a number3= !number3! +5  
        set /a number4= !number4! +20  
    )  
)  
goto echo  
:echo  
echo !numbercheck!  
echo !number2!  
echo !number3!  
echo !number4!  
pause
```

Comment: You have a typo: `if !numbercheck GEQ 10` => `if !numbercheck! GEQ 10`

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 And a missing `/l`. See my answer.

Comment: Aside from all of this, use PowerShell instead. The syntax is far simpler, more readable, and less cumbersome.

Answer (score 2):

#### I'm not sure what's wrong - the expected output is `0 5 25 100`

> The output I get is `20 3 15 60`
>
> ...
>
> ```
> for %%a in (0, 1, 100) do (  
>     if !numbercheck GEQ 10 (
> ```
>
> ...

There are two mistakes in the above code:

1. Missing `/l` in the `for` command, it should be:

   ```
   for /l %%a in (0, 1, 100) do (
   ```

   Without the `/l` the `for` loop will return 0,1,100 and will only loop 3 times. With the `/l` the `for` loop will return 1,2,3,...,100
2. Missing `!` in the `if` command, it should be:

   ```
   if !numbercheck! GEQ 10 (
   ```

**Corrected batch file:**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion  
cls  
:vars  
set numbercheck=50  
set number2=0  
set number3=0  
set number4=0  
:calc  
for /l %%a in (0, 1, 100) do (  
    if !numbercheck! GEQ 10 (  
        set /a numbercheck= !numbercheck! - 10  
        set /a number2= !number2! +1  
        set /a number3= !number3! +5  
        set /a number4= !number4! +20  
    )  
)  
goto echo  
:echo  
echo !numbercheck!  
echo !number2!  
echo !number3!  
echo !number4!  
pause
```

**Example output:**

```
0
5
25
100
Press any key to continue . . .
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /l](http://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html) - Conditionally perform a command for a range of numbers.